# Better Random Number Ranges In Swift 3

Tags: random, sprite-kit, swift3, gameplay-kit

Before I upgraded to Swift 3 (Xcode 8) my random position start looked like this:

```
func randomStartPosition(range: Range<Int> = 45...(Int(self.frame.size.height)-45)) -> Int {
    let min = range.startIndex
    let max = range.endIndex
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min }
```

Which stopped working after the conversion because it was updated to this:

```
func randomSmallObjectsStartPosition(_ range: Range<Int> = 25...(Int(self.frame.size.height)-25)) -> Int {
    let min = range.lowerBound
    let max = range.upperBound
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min }
```

Which was worked out because I ended up learning about GamePlayKit:

Start by:

```
import GameplayKit
```

Then you can easily make new random variables using GamePlayKit:

You can read up on the apple site but basically this gives you more "hits" in the middle:

```
lazy var randomStartPosition = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: GKARC4RandomSource(), lowestValue: 0, highestValue:100)
```

And this will cycle through the random values until they are all consumed, then start again.

```
lazy var randomShuffle = GKShuffledDistribution(randomSource: GKARC4RandomSource(), lowestValue: 0, highestValue:100)
```

And lastly the totally random value generator:

```
lazy var totallyRandom = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 100)
```

An example of how to use:

```
    MyObject.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 20, y: CGFloat(totallyRandom.nextInt()) )
```

This will put my object off the screen on the far right and put it at a completely random position on the Y axis.

Comment: why do you use lazy vars?

Comment: I was monitoring memory usage when I was playing with this and the lazy var dropped the memory leak.  Sorry if I confused anyone, I am still debugging the memory in the application this is used in.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I understand lazy vars, but this gives me some motivation to try.